# $(window).scroll in vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scroll, requestanimationframe

1. What's the equivalent of the following in plain JS?

   `$(window).scroll(function() { });`
2. I'm also looking to animate scroll, e.g.:

   `$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:1750}, 'slow');`

Should I be using `requestAnimationFrame`?

http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Are there any examples that trigger an animation once on click and not continuous renders?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

### Question 1

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    console.log('scrolling');
};
```

or if your [targeted browsers support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=addeventlistener) `addEventListener` :

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
        console.log('scrolling');
});
```

### Question 2

In my opinion, if you're just scrolling from one section to a another section of your page, and not having some sort of constantly running scrolling movement, you're fine doing this without using requestAnimationFrame.

You can find good implementations of scrolling to a particular part of the window in pure javascript, I suggest checking out their source(or even using them).

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "if its supported"? Is this because some browsers (IE) don't support `addEventListener`, or is it that they don't fire the `scroll` event?

Comment: @WillBrickner I meant if `addEventListener` is supported. Editing now for clarity.

Comment: Be careful if you use window.onscroll though. If you have two functions which you append to the window one of them will not work as you overwrite the previous function. This will result in a difficult to debug problem.

Comment: Is it possible to modify this solution so the function will be called on scroll only once?

Comment: @OlgaB You can do this by wrapping the scroll handler in a debounce function. You can find good implementations of them in common JavaScript libraries or implement debouncing yourself (it's a great way to understand closures and higher-order functions).

Comment: @JonathanF I know about a debounce function but never tried it. Thank you very much! Good point. :)